# Why is my code for Cropping Multiple Images using OpenCV and saving them to a Folder not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, for-loop, image-processing

I am preparing a dataset for object detection, so I want to crop thousands of images and below is my code:

```
for i in os.listdir('diri'):
   if not (i.endswith('.png') or i.endswith('.jpg')):
      continue
   img= cv2.imread(i)
   crop= img[240:400,0:480]
   cv2.imwrite('Cropped/{0}'.format(i),crop)
```

This gives the below error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a53199d54e32> in <module>
  4         continue
  5     img= cv2.imread(i)
----> 6     crop= img[240:400,0:480]
  7     cv2.imwrite('Cropped/{0}'.format(i),crop)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

But when I take the same image and perform the operation out of the loop, it works, so I don't know how the image is being returned as None.

I also tried another method as below:

```
import glob
images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("./diri/*.jpg")]
for i in images:
   crop= i[240:400,0:480]
   cv2.imwrite('Cropped/{0}.jpg'.format(i),crop)
```

The above gets executed without any errors but there are no cropped images in the o/p folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only passing the image name to the `cv2.imread(i)`. Since the images are placed inside the folder `"diri"`. Therefore you get the `NoneType` error.

Change the code to:

`imgpath = os.path.join("diri", i)`

`cv2.imread(imgpath)`

For the second method, make sure you have the `Cropped` directory in parallel with `diri`.